# Overload array subscript operator

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there any way to overload the array subscript operator in C++ other than in a class? I would like to call a user-defined function when reading/writing in the array.

For example:

```
int* array = new int[10];
array[0] = 5;
```

When writing in array[0], I would like to call my own function. I know it can be done inside a class by overloading the operator[] (for example, a SafeArray class).

Thanks.

Comment: Probably no, as this just decomposes to pointer setting, not a function call.

Comment: You can't overload pointer dereference like that (`array[0]` is equivalent to `*(array + 0)`).

Comment: No you can't. As a simple rule of thumb, all user-defined operators must take at least one parameter of a user-defined type (including the hidden `this` for a member function).

Comment: If it was possible, code using this would be so unreadable...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a wrapper class, something like:

```
template<typename T>
struct SubscriptWrapper {
    SubscriptWrapper(T* array) : array_(array) {};
    T& operator[](size_t index) { 
        // your magic goes in here
    };
    T* array_;
}
```